# Java - Learning MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, design-patterns

I wish to learn how to apply MVC architecture to my Java project; mainly my work in Swing. Now there is no easy explanation or example how to write proper code using MVC in mind apart from these two I found here:

1. http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html
2. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html

It seems to me there is not a defined MVC architecture in Java. From what I looked at it's what Java offers you at the base level of Wwing and what you can apply on your own is in the first tutorial.

Apart from the two resources above, can someone provide me with a source that can ease you in to Java MVC?  A video tutorial maybe?

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gui problem after rewriting to MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc)

Comment: have your model extend http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html. have your view implement http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html

Comment: This is the simplest tutorial I could find: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm After u understand the whole concept you will be able to easily understand more complex

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is pretty nice example http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/structure/40mvc.html I tried to find simplest possible to let you feel the idea.

Anyway I don't like the:

> Seems to me there is not a defined MVC architecture in Java.

You can use MVC, MVP and whole other patterns in various different languages. Java has nothing to do with MVC, except MVC design can be coded in Java. There are, however, some frameworks that have embedded MVC architecture and forces using it. **Spring MVC** is the most known - try to find more about it, maybe some tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

**Model** - Model represents an object or JAVA POJO carrying data. It can also have logic to update controller if its data changes.

**View** - View represents the visualization of the data that model contains.

**Controller** - Controller acts on both Model and view. It controls the data flow into model object and updates the view whenever data changes. It keeps View and Model separate.

[mvc simple example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm)

Answer (score 3):

see this example [mvc simple example](http://padmanlabs.blogspot.in/2012/08/mvc-architecture-simple-java.html)  which is adding two numbers program using swings.by this example you can easily understud the concept of mvc

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [spring](http://www.springsource.org/) framework, you can use it also with swing as shown in [this](http://java.dzone.com/news/spring-enabling-decoupled-swin) tutorial .

Comment: Spring is overkill for someone trying to understand the basics of Swing and MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Using Javas in-built capabilities of the so called **Observer** and **Observable** classes the following tutorial explains the concept of MVC by an example.

[MVC by Example with observer and observeable classes](http://www.austintek.com/mvc/)