# How to go from jinternalform to another jinternalform

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, jinternalframe

In my java swing project I'm using JFrame Form named as Home. It is acully home page linked to other jinternalFrame Forms. I have made one jinternalForm Frame named as Invoice. And I put a button as DamageItem. When I'm click that button I want to go to another jinternalform Frame called Stock. How can I link that. I made a object of Stock.

```
Stock st = new Stock();
```

but Still I can't use this method which I use in Home to call that Stock. It is like. .

```
Stock st = new Stock(); 
jDesktopPane1.add(st);
```

And I changed jinternalFrame's variable modifier as `"Public"`.

But Still I can't use it. How can I call one jinternalFrame Form to another.

I'm using netbeans 7.3

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Comment: I'm sorry this question was so stupid.. Actually I forgot to put st.setVisible(true); Code part to actually load the interface. This question was happened my lack of knowledge on java before...  Thank you for your time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I get your question but if you're what you are trying to achieve is to interact between 2 JInternalFrames, you should consider looking at the MVC pattern ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

You could basically have a view, a jframe which owns 2 jinternalframes. These jinternalframes have view elements, like jbuttons. You would then invoke an external controller each time one of these buttons is invoked to do whichever action you wish to do. Ideally, you would also have a model (logical entity) displayed by the views and you would act on this model from within your controller.
It's hard to resume all of this in a few lines but you should take the time to read documentation and tutorials on this programming paradigm. Also there were already some StackOverflow threads about this. [MVC links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693815/java-learning-mvc)

Comment: This helps a lot more than I thought.