# Using MVC/MVP for Swing UI?

Tags: java, swing

Till now I have worked with some java swing code with everything in  one class. 
I want design and develop better UI application. Trying to use MVP/MVC for swing UI, didn't found any concrete example anywhere.

I want to develop swing UI form with submit button. i.e. this main panel representing user form contains three panels:
    - Header panel with combo box and text fields.
    - Center panel with table pane.
    - End panel with some combo box and text fields.

So basically I have written 4 UI classes with no action listeners, one for main and three for header,center and end panel. Executing Main panel show me all the components.

I want to provide runtime data to combo box and when user submit I should get selected values from combo box and other fields.
How should I design using  MVP/MVC. Could any one provide some explanation or give me a link to any reference or example?

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing

Comment: Or the example seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3066590/230513).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Links provided help in getting some understanding of using MVC in swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this: [Java - Learning MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693815/java-learning-mvc)

The MVC pattern requires these 3 classes.

- theModel: handles data
- theView:  handles GUI
- theController: handles listeners.

You may need some understanding of the Observer pattern first.

the design may be as follows:

```
public class Test {

    public Test(){
       MyModel      model      = new MyModel();
       MyController controller = new MyController(model);
    }
}
```

controller class

```
public class MyController implements ActionListener {
    private MyView view;
    private MyModel model;

    MyController(MyModel theModel){
        model = theModel;
        view = new MyView(this);
        model.register(view);
    }

    // implement actionPerformed here
}
```

view class

```
public class View implements Observer {
    private MyController controller;

    public View(){
         // Swing Components here
         JButton button = new JButton();
         button.addActionListener(controller);
         add(button);
    }
    // notifyObserver method implementation
}
```

model class

```
public class MyModel extends Observable {
    // handle state/data changes here

}
```