# Java JFrame not displaying desired graphics

Tags: java

I had glitching in speech marks because I am farily sure it is not a glitch.

I have just recently started to code using JFrames, in fact I started Java at school couple months ago, but recently I have tried to push my understanding using these handy frames.

I made a program which would bounce a ball around the frame, and I wanted to make it so there would be 2 (for now they would not collide) however whenever I try to add another it simply shows one. 
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello There");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    Main ball = new Main();
    Main ball2 = new Main();
    ball2.SetValues(200, 200, Color.BLUE);
    frame.add(ball2);
    frame.add(ball);

    while (true) {
        ball.move();
        ball.repaint();
        ball2.move();
        ball2.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }
}

public void move() {

    x = x + xDirection;
    y = y + yDirection;
    if (x < 0) { //If Ball has gone off the screen on x direction
        xDirection = 1; //Start moving to the right
    } else if (x > getWidth() - 50) { //If x has gone off the screen to the right
        xDirection = -1;//Start moving to the left
    }

    if (y < 0) { //If Ball has gone off the screen on x direction
        yDirection = 1; //Start moving to the right
    } else if (y > getHeight() - 50) { //If x has gone off the screen to the right
        yDirection = -1;//Start moving to the left
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

I recently added the line "frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()" and it appears to show the 2 balls but they are in a glitched state.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: There is a subroutine which I did not add which is "SetValues", it just sets the classes values depending on what is sent through, self explanatory really.

Comment: You are doing everything inside the UI thread and that could cause the issue. Use a separate thread for the `while` block, or replace it entirely by using a Timer.

Comment: Thread.sleep(5) means you are trying to execute the loop *two hundred* times per second.  I doubt you want that.  Also, modifying your `x` and `y` fields does not in itself move the component.  Consider editing your question and showing us the entire class, so we can test it for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

You should not sleep or do any long process on `Swing` thread, nor should you update the gui from other threads. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
One alternative is to use `javax.swing.Timer` :

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {       
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ball.move();
            ball.repaint();
            ball2.move();
            ball2.repaint();        
        }
 });
 timer.start();
```

Another alternative is to use a [separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54881063/3992939)

It is also recommended to read [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: It appears the sleep calls are in the main thread, not the AWT event dispatch thread.